# Android app requires Google Play Service Update - Open button instead of Update

Tags: android

In order to use GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) I need to implement Google Play Service library in my application. Everything works on my Galaxy S2 (Android 4.1.2) but on my HTC (Android 2.2.2) I can't update Google Play Service.

When application is creating (onCreate), I check if Google Play Service is installed or its need to be updated:

```
public static boolean isGooglePlayServiceEnabled(Context context)
{
    return GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS ? true : false;
}
```

In my activity:

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
{
    // Some code....
    if (!isGooglePlayInstalled(this))
    {
        int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(instance)
        if (errorCode == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED)
        {
            // Alert Dialog and prompt user to update App
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.gms")));
        }
    }
}
```

User is redirected to Market to update Google Play Service. But when he arrives, there is no "Update" button! It's only 2 buttons: "Open" and "Uninstall" !

What should I do?

**UPDATE**

I just found out that Google drops support for Android <= 8 (2.2.2).

> With over 97% of devices now running Android 2.3 (Gingerbread) or
>   newer platform versions, we’re dropping support for Froyo from this
>   release of the Google Play services SDK in order to make it possible
>   to offer more powerful APIs in the future. That means you will not be
>   able to utilize these new APIs on devices running Android 2.2 (Froyo).

Comment: There is Google Play Services for froyo. If you use the 'Google Play Services for Froyo', you will not be able to use the new features included in Google Play Service 4.0. For Maps, the 4.0 features include

Answer (score 0):

There is no current version of Google Play Services for your device. If there is no update available the PlayStore will just offer you to *open* the application.