# Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver

Tags: android, firebase

I recently updated my app on Google Play and saw a crash the error message is this:

```
Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
```

The update only changed the frequency of ads, nothing else. I'm using firebase-core and firebase-ads.
The crash only happens when the app is installed from the Play Store and not over adb or installing the APK on the device locally - the crash is also seems to only happen on the first open.
For now, I have removed firebase-core and firebase-ads from my app and am waiting for the app to update on the store.

Update: Removing firebase-core and firebase-ads seems to have fixed the issue. Although, I would still like to have firebase in my app.

Thanks.

Comment: Explore your final *.apk with apk analyzer tool (the Android Studio have one) and see if it really contains the class missed.

Comment: Do you obfuscate your code using Proguard?

Comment: I am not using firebase in my project. but the issue exists. Have any other solution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google FireBase depends on Google Play Services being installed on the client device.

You need to ensure that the user has the latest Google Play Services installed on his device, and prompt him to update and/or install when needed:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk

And a quick code snippet that does just that:
[Android app requires Google Play Service Update - Open button instead of Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066493/android-app-requires-google-play-service-update-open-button-instead-of-update)

Comment: On my test device I have the lastest Google Play Services installed and the app still crashed.

Comment: I have the latest version of Google Play Services as well at the error is still there.

Answer (score 1):

If your app contains of Firebase Analytics. You need to declared `BroadcastReceiver` in AndroidManifest.xml and enabled:

```
<manifest>
   <application>
     <!-- ... -->

     <receiver
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
         android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
         android:enabled="true">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
         </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

     <!-- ... -->
   </application>
 </manifest>
```

It said in Google API here: 
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver, I solved my problem by doing this

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ProGuard file:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
```

or

```
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
```

depending on which package you use for your ads.

Answer (score 0):

```
Broadcast of Intent { act=com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER flg=0x10 pkg=com.company.appname cmp=com.company.appname/com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver (has extras) }
```

My application still has the above error, I use and test on the virtual machine android API 26 and 28 no problem

**com.company.appname** is the name has been changed